# visual foxpro - need to update table from another table

Tags: foxpro

I have 2 dbf tables and I need to update the 1st table based from the 2nd table values.
I am able to do it in SQL server and I need help on Visual Foxpro.

Here's my foxpro command:

=========================================================

```
use table1

use table2

UPDATE table1 

SET table1.name = table2.name 

from table1 inner join table2 

on table1.id = table2.id 

WHERE table1.dsdate >= {^2011-04-13} and table1.dsdate <= {^2012-04-12}
```

=========================================================

Please help me, thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

```
Update Table1 From table2 Where table1.id = table2.id ;
Set table1.name = table2.name
```

Comment: The only things I would add are: 1) you can add the rest of the date filter to the WHERE clause using the AND operator 2) this won't work in VFP6, but will in VFP9 (not sure about VFP7 and VFP8).