# updating a table in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

There are two tables in my database. I am trying to update a column in table2 by setting it equal to one of the columns in table1. I've already looked at this answer [visual foxpro - need to update table from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812474/visual-foxpro-need-to-update-table-from-another-table)
And tried to do this on my code, however, I kept having a syntax error on UPDATE table2. Why?
Here is what I have.

```
ALTER TABLE table2;
ADD COLUMN base2 B(8,2);
UPDATE table2
WHERE table2.itemid=table1.itemid from table1;
SET table2.base2=table1.base;
```

Comment: You should only tag the question with the actual database you're using. If you're using Visual Foxpro, you don't need the final `;` in the update command.

Comment: Ok! I will erase the sql language. I deleted the final ; and still am getting the syntax error

Comment: When I erased all ";" It seems like my problem is the add column clause

Comment: Actually it appears you're using the `;` wrong. You only need one at the end of a line that's being continued. Try writing each command on one line, rather than breaking it into multiple lines.

Comment: I did that, and still got a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'standard' VFP language syntax and RELATED Tables, you could quite easily do the following:

```
USE Table1 IN 0 EXCLUSIVE
SELECT Table1
INDEX ON ID TAG ID  && Create Index on ID field
USE Table2 IN 0
SELECT Table2
SET RELATION TO ID INTO Table1
REPLACE ALL Table2.ID WITH Table1.ID FOR !EMPTY(Table2.ID)
```

You might want to spend some time looking over the free, on-line tutorial videos at: [Learn Visual Foxpro @ garfieldhudson.com](http://www.garfieldhudson.com/freevideos.aspx)
The videos named:
* Building a Simple Application - Pt. 5
 and
* Q&A: Using Related Tables In A Report
Both discuss using VFP's language to work with Related Tables

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The simplest syntax is:

```
update table2 from table1 where table2.itemid = table1.itemid ;
set table2.base2 = table1.base
```

You could also add more fields to update separated by commas, i.e.

```
... set table2.base2 = table1.base, table2.this = table1.that
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
          Update table2 b 
         Join table1 a on b. Itemid=a.itemid
          Set b. Base2=a.base
```

Comment: I still have the same issue changing to what you have

Comment: Could you please post complete error that thrown to you

Comment: Yes. The original error is Syntax error, changing to yours also I have Syntax error.

Comment: You are missing semicolons at the end of lines and have an extra space after b. Also aliasing table2 as in "Update table2 b ..." wouldn't work in VFP  (not only VFP really). And also you have set in the wrong place.